# Embedding d3.js graph in a web2py bootstrap page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, d3.js, web2py

Below is an example of how I am using d3.js with web2py controller. This is working for me.

But, I would prefer to use d3.js within an existing bootstrap page using web2py's default bootstrap layout. When I put this d3.js code into the bootstrap layout it does not cause any errors, but I am not seeing an `<svg>` tag appended to `<body>`.

Can someone post an example of how this can be done?

`controllers/d3js.py`:

```
import random 
def histogram():
    dataset = [(random.randint(1,6) + random.randint(1,6)) for i in range(100)]
    return dict(dataset=dataset, title='D3.js Histogram')
```

`view/d3js/histogram.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>{{=title}}</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" ></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            {{from gluon.serializers import json}}
            var dataset = {{=XML(json(dataset))}};

            //Width and height
            var w = 600;
            var h = 600;
            ...

            //Create SVG element
            var svg = d3.select("body")
                        .append("svg")
                        .attr("width", w)
                        .attr("height", h);

            ...

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The source of [this d3.js sample](http://examples.oreilly.com/0636920026938/chapter_10/14_div_tooltip.html) is Scott Murray's book, [Interactive Data Visualizations for the Web](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000345).

Comment: The above code works?  *When I put this d3.js code into the bootstrap layout*, what does that code look like?

Answer (score 0):

In /views/default/histogram.html, if you have:

```
{{extend 'layout.html'}}
[Your D3 HTML code]
```

this will cause a problem because everything after the `{{extend}}` statement gets inserted where the `{{include}}` appears in layout.html, which is within the `<body>` tag (so, you are including a new `<html>` tag and `<body>` tag within the existing `<body>` tag).

Instead, in your histogram.html view, include only the parts of the HTML that are inside the `<body>` tag. In that case, you will also need to make sure the D3 library gets loaded, so you could either move that `<script>` tag inside the body, or you could add it via web2py's `response.files`:

```
response.files.append('https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js')
```